# What is the oldest math source that we know of?

Tags: math-history

What is the oldest math source that we know of? Or to put it differently, what is the first math that was ever done?

Comment: It might be better to post this question on http://hsm.stackexchange.com/ instead of this site.

Comment: FFR, it is almost always a bad idea to echo the tags in the title, or use "question" at all. *Everything* is a question (in theory) so it is not usually useful.

Comment: I'm 58. Not sure about the oldest.

Comment: @WillJagy hahaha great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Ishango bone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishango_bone) is one candidate.  Of course it may depend on how you define "math".

Answer (score 6):

The [Moscow Mathematical Papyrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Mathematical_Papyrus) is nearly 4,000 years old. It is much newer than the Ishango bone, but is unquestionably mathematical.  The [Berlin Papyrus 6619](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Papyrus_6619) may be slightly older.

There are also a large number of extant  [Babylonian clay tablets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babylonian_mathematics) of about the same age or possibly a little older.

Wikipedia has a [timeline of mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_mathematics) whose early part may be interesting.

Comment: The Babylonian tablets from around 1700 BC include exercises in solving quadratic equations. _Episodes from the Early History of Mathematics,_ by Asger Aaboe, includes a fairly accessible description of these tablets.

Answer (score 1):

Euclid's Elements is worth mentioning as one of the oldest sources of math that approximately reflects how many areas of mathematics is done today, that is, start with axioms, and derive theorems. It's probably the among the oldest things that sort-of resembles a modern textbook. Euclid even left "exercises for the reader".